# cppunittest.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild

I try build an unit test C++ project on a CI server. On my PC no problem, but on the CI server, I have the message: "'CppUnitTest.h' : No such file or directory".

On both computer (mine and server), there is VS enterprise 2017, the only thing different it's on my PC, I build on VS, and on the CI server, I use MSBuild by command line.

I tried to include additional directories in the project as:

AdditionalIncludeDirectories: $(VCInstallDir)Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include;$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

AdditionalLibraryDirectories - $(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib;$(VCInstallDir)Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

But it doesn't work.
Is there another directory to include ?

Comment: Since you have install the VS enterprise 2017  on the CI server, have you tired to build the project with Visual Studio 2017 directly on the CI server? Check if you still have this issue, if not, please share the command line and the parameters when you build via msbuild.

Comment: I tried on the CI server with VS enterprise, it works. There is the command line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=C:/project\coding_rule_cpp.ruleset /maxcpucount:4 C:/project\UnitTests\UnitTests.vcxproj "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cppunittest.h no such file or directory

Since you have installed the Visual Studio 2017 on your build server and build the project successfully, you should use the MSBuild from the Visual Studio instead of the build tool.

You can try to call the MSBuild from following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

I have create a unit test C++ project sample to test, and it works fine, if I call the MSBuild from above folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To conclude, MSBuild from the build tool doesn't compile C++ unit test (but it does with C# unit test, I do this on another project)... I hope MStest works too. thanks for the helps.